# How Can I Create an Intent to 'Open In App' but Not from the Browser

Tags: android, xml

I've got an intent in my `AndroidManifest.xml` working great. When a person visits a page called "train", the actions specified in my `ActivityMain` are carried out.

However, my website includes some features which are not available in my app.

So i'd still like users to be able to navigate around my website with ease, without links to the train page on the *browser* opening the app.

Does anyone know how I can use an `intent-filter` to prompt the user with the option to "open in app" from apps such as Gmail, Messenger, etc, but NOT when they're on my website going to the specified page?

```
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:host="example.co.uk"/>
            <data android:path="/train/"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="example.co.uk"
        android:path="/train/"
        android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

For further information you can view detail here about deep linking:
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

Comment: Thanks but when I click the link to train page through browser (ie on website), it still prompts to open in app. Which part of your answer is supposed to not open via browser?

Comment: Then you should change your website code so that he will not show that button on a specific page.